# Javascript Equivalent of Python's operator.add

Tags: javascript, python

Does javascript have an equivalent to Python's `operator.add`, or any other binary operators?

In Python:

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

# prints 15, requires defining the addition operator
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

# prints 15, does not require defining the addition operator
print(reduce(add, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

In Javascript:

```js
// prints 15, requires defining the addition operator
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((a,b) => a + b))

// is there a way to do this without defining the addition operator?
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have done it is the most concise way that I'm aware of in JavaScript.  You might want to supply a default value for your `reduce` to protect against an empty input array:

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0))

// throws a TypeError...
console.log([].reduce((a,b) => a + b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a low level language : no way until you define it.

See [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

```
const add = (acc, item) => {
    return acc = acc + item;
});

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(add, 0));
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have a built-in function to add an array of numbers, but it's hardly a low-level language.  That means something specific in computer science.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language